# How to create and build an ESP-IDF static library?

Tags: makefile, static-libraries

I'm learning ESP-IDF platform and now want to create a library in order to be able to structure my code properly in the future.

I've done some research and found few things, for instance a [library](https://github.com/Gfast2/open62541_port/tree/master/components/open62541) that could be as an example. The only issue with it being too large, I can't clearly see what's the bare minimum for the simplest library code.

What is the minimum configuration for an ESP-IDF static library that can be built into a `.a` file?

Answer (score 1):

A minimal ESP-IDF component would have an empty component.mk file, C/C++/ASM source file(s), and header file(s) in `include` subdirectory. At build time, all source files of the component will be compiled and then linked into a static library, which can be found in `build/component_name/libcomponent_name.a`. This is further explained in [ESP-IDF build system documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/build-system.html#minimal-component-makefile).

There are a few such simple components in the ESP-IDF itself, e.g. [log](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components/log).